# what's the benefit of diffusion models reverse process

Tags: image-generation, diffusion-models

To draw a picture, we have two approaches:

1. gradually add(and modify) pixels on white paper.
2. gradually remove(and modify) pixels from a complete random noise picture.

Apparently, the diffusion model belongs to the second one. What's the benefit of using the second one rather than the first one?

Comment: One advantage is that you don't get the same picture every time, because there is randomness. Your pictures aren't biased towards white, either. (why should it be white and not for example blue?)

Comment: there are "inpainting" models which operate by adding pixels to parts of images where there are no pixels at all